# Mix at position audio files NAudio

Tags: vb.net, naudio

I'd like to mix some audio files at a specific position.

In example i have a musical base and I want to overlay a speech at a certain time position (the theme starts and then after 3 seconds i want to have my voice on) and than export to a wave file.

For now i can mix several audio files but starting all at the same time with this:
`element` is the object containing the filname of the audio samples

```
    Dim audioReaders As New List(Of Wave.AudioFileReader)
    For Each element In elements
        Dim myReader As New NAudio.Wave.AudioFileReader(element.Filename)
        audioReaders.Add(myReader)
    Next

    Dim mixer As New NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders.MixingSampleProvider(audioReaders)

    NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16("mixed.wav", mixer)
```

How can i do it using Naudio in vb.net?